# Importing resource file to PyQt code?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have seen Qt documentary and a lot of questions less-similar to this one, But i still haven't figured out how can i do it.

I'm not entirely sure how can i import resource file to Python code, so pixmap appears without any issues.

---

I have all files in same directory, I created qrc. file and compiled it with: `rcc -binary resources.qrc -o res.rcc` to make resource file.

I imported res_rcc but pixmap on label was still not shown:

`import res_rcc`

---

This is what i had in my qrc. file:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>download.jpeg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

## Question:

How can i import resource files in the PyQt code ?  **|**  If pixmaps are in same directory as .qrc resource files, Do i still need to specify full path?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For pyqt you have to use pyrcc4, which is the equivalent of rcc for python.

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

This generates the resources.py module that needs to be imported in the python code in order to make the resources available.

```
import resources
```

To use the resource in your code you have to use the ":/" prefix:

Example

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import resources

pixmap = QPixmap(":/newPrefix/download.jpeg")
```

See [The PyQt4 Resource System](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/resources.html) and [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: i still couldn't see the pixmap, do i have something wrong inside it? I have everything in the same directory, so i'm not entirely sure, how can i add images to resources and then use it in code.

Comment: It still wouldn't show, But, do i need to use that import preferences?, I tried those and it gave me this error:   `File "project.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined`

Comment: Heres what i did add in home function:   `def home(self):
        pic = QtGui.QLabel()
        pic.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/download.jpeg"))
        self.show()`

Comment: If you use from `PyQt4.QtGui import *`, you must use `QLabel` etc. without `QtGui`. If  you use `from PyQt4 import QtGui`, you have to use `QtGui.QLabel` etc.

Comment: The image still, wouldn't show, This is what i changed in qrc file, before compiling it `<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="images">
    <file>download.jpeg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>` and i called it for pixmap, like this:         `pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/download.jpeg"))` @Fabio

Comment: Are you sure that pyrcc4 ends without errors? The resulting resources.py must be a quite big file.

Comment: Yes, it generated file without printing anything in console, Is something wrong with my home function code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109364/discussion-between-fabio-and-shellrox).

Answer (score 13):

In PyQt5, we should write in comand line

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resource/resources.qrc
```

Because, we need to generate a resource.py to import in the code. Now we can type

```
import resources
```

in our python code

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above wonderful answers, if you would also like the ability to set the icon from within QtCreator itself (instead of having to do the say `setWindowIcon(QIcon('://images/app_icon.ico'))` line in code), you do this:

`pyrcc5 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
cd ui
pyuic5 -o dialog.py dialog.ui`

*(Note that `pyuic5` automatically imports `resources_rc` and not `resources` for some reason; hence the new name specified above)*

Where you've made sure that:

```
...
</tabstops>
 <resources>
  <include location="../resources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
<connections>
...
```

appears approximately there (between `tabstops` and `connections`) in your `dialog.ui` file.  I think to get it there automatically, you can create a dummy C++ project and add your .ui files to the dummy project, then add a new Qt Resource file to the project.  When your done, you can delete everything leaving the .ui files and the .qrc file.  If you happen to copy `resources.qrc` to another directory, then closing and re-opening the `dialog.ui` file will prompt you for where the new location is.

Now you can set the resources from the **Property** explorer on in QtCreator: `windowIcon > Choose Resource > (click on the root) > (your files should show up now) > (select app_icon.ico)`.

---

I just checked a newly created `mainwindow.ui`, if you open up the file in **Text Edit** mode in Qt Creator it shows you where the `<resource />` stub is.  Simply insert there (using some other program)  For some reason opening up the newly created .ui file in Notepad++ was not showing it.

---

When closing and re-opening files, you must actually close the file (not "Reload" - doesn't work) and open it again.  Then the resource root in "add image from resources" dialog will be non-empty.