# Qt Designer error with Python throwing error when I try to load image

Tags: python, image, qt-designer

I'm trying to load a logo into a python scripts UI.  I'm using Qt Designer and I created a label and set pixmap to the image.  The image loads fine in the designer but when I import the ui file into the python script I get this error message

```
C:\Users\Mason\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/Mason/PycharmProjects/Inspector/Tester/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mason/PycharmProjects/Inspector/Tester/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    UIClass, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("ui5.ui")
  File "C:\Users\Mason\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 201, in loadUiType
    exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
  File "<string>", line 30
    import 3_rc
```

I still get that error even if I take the image out of the ui file and reload it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
import sys


UIClass, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("ui5.ui")

class MyApp(UIClass, QtBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        UIClass.__init__(self)
        QtBaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushbutton_click)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to load the image in the label?

Comment: Just added some code.  The .ui file is auto generated by Qt Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Qt relies on a resource system for images and other assets. When you add an image in qt designer, it creates a resource file. You have to convert that resource file, just like with a ui file (`uic` is a shortcut [to this process](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)). The autogenerated ui file you get with `uic` is looking for that resource file, but can't find it.

You can convert your resource file to python with this, depending on your qt version:
`pyrcc5 -o 3_rc.py your_resource_file_here.qrc`

More info:

- Related question: [Importing resource file to PyQt code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673900/importing-resource-file-to-pyqt-code)
- https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/resources.html
- https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/resources.html

Comment: Yep this worked.  Thanks for the tip.  Just an fyi for anyone else reading this if you're using PyQT5 you will have to remove a line called import 3_rc from the code once you convert it from a ui to a .py.  and you will have to change <scr:\ > to to just the file path as well.